# How do I load assets from npm/bower using a gulp-based asset pipeline with Rails? (ripped out sprockets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, gulp, bower

I have taken out Sprockets and went with Gulp for managing assets. I use npm and bower for package management, both of which tie into Gulp for moving to `/public/assets/`.

I'm used to sprockets' manifest requires with //= in app.(css|js). How would I go about requiring/importing in this new setup?

I imagine an ES6 syntax using require for JS, but less certain on @import'ing CSS from node_modules and bower_components in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Use `main-bower-assets` with gulp to load from bower_components and gulp-sass's `includePaths` option for setting directories to search for fulfilling @imports in sass. Seems ES6's require works fine for JS.